# Vegas 2 slider loading to two elements bug - Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

When I used this slider to one element, the problem didn't exist. When I use this slider to two elements, console shows the error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()."

On the documentation of slider (http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/), slider works on two elements, but on my website not. I use 3.2.1 JQuery and lasted version of slider. I load the slider to two elements with this command:

```
$("body, #example").vegas(...);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know now what was wrong. Vegas 2 makes errors when it loads the same vidoe to two elements. The solution is makes copy of the video which has diffrent name and create two vegas commends.